# spring data postgresql save default value when null

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data

I have a postgred db and table there with the following column:

```
 TIMESTAMP BIGINT DEFAULT (date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * (1000)::DOUBLE PRECISION) NOT NULL,
```

I want to store there milliseconds count like System.currentTimeMillis in Java.
I want postgres to do that for me on every insert. But I can't store a record with null timestamp like I could in mysql. I want it to trigger def. value when column is null. I have a spring data jpa class with column:

```
@Column(nullable = false,
            columnDefinition = "BIGINT DEFAULT (date_part('epoch'::text, now()) * (1000)::DOUBLE PRECISION) NOT NULL")
    public BigDecimal getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
```

but neither this, nor

```
@Column(insertable=false,...)
```

works. Also I have a repository where this column also involved

```
@Query( "select c from ChatMessages c where"
            + " c.messageType in (:messageTypes) "
            + "and c.clientType=:clientType "
            + "and c.nextMessageId is null "
            + " and c.processed=0 "
            + "and c.timestamp+:delta<=:currentTimestamp" )
    List<ChatMessages> findEligibleRecords(
            @Param("currentTimestamp") Long currentTimestamp,
            @Param("delta") Long delta,
            @Param("clientType") ClientTypeEnum clientType,
            @Param("messageTypes") MessageTypes... messageType);
```

And I can't get it work. I want the value to be stored ONLY by postgres, but being read by jpa. How to achieve that?

Comment: In postgres `DEFAULT` will replace any `NULL` I think you want [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtrigger.html) `on BEFORE INSERT`

Comment: Thanks, but it sounds weird coz it's pretty simple for db like postgres. Nayway, I will do thigger, but how to tell hibernate to use this colums as read only?

Comment: Also, default does not replace null for me. I tried everything, it simple complains all the time.

Comment: I don't think default should replace nulls, it should only set values not part of the insert.